# Could not find include include file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, cloud9

I'm running a simple server

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); 
app.use(express.static('public')) 

// home page request handler
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.render('home')
})

// initializes request listener
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server is listening");
})
```

When I make a GET request for the home page, run-time throws the following error

```
Error: Could not find include include file.
    at getIncludePath (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:152:13)
    at includeSource (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:276:17)
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:629:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.generateSource (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:605:15)
    at Object.compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:509:12)
    at Object.compile (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:358:16)
    at handleCache (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:201:18)
    at tryHandleCache (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:223:14)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/workspace/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:437:10)
```

I don't understand this error. Any ideas? I'm working in Cloud9.

My directory structure is

```
v1.1
  +---views
  |     +---- home.ejs
  |     +---- partials
  |               +------ header.ejs
  |               +------ footer.ejs
  |
  +----app.js
```

`home.ejs`

```
<% include header %>
<h1>welcome</h1>
<% include footer %>
```

`header.ejs`

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" hreff="app.css">
            </title>
        </head>
    <body>
```

`footer.ejs`

```
    </body
</html>
```

Comment: Have you run [`npm i ejs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs)?

Comment: @zero298 yes i ran `npm install ejs`

Comment: Do you have a file called `home.ejs` in a directory called `/views/`?

Comment: @zero298 yes I do

Comment: What does home.ejs look like? Error suggests an issue including a partial view

Comment: @James I added the file you asked for

Comment: `<% include partials/footer %>`

Comment: No probs, must say `ejs` error is not very helpful..  The include file might have helped.. :)  Also the other guys helped here, getting you to show more details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Include paths are relative, you will need to update your paths to include the "partials" subfolder e.g.

```
<% include partials/header %>
<h1>welcome</h1>
<% include partials/footer %>
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/tj/ejs/blob/master/Readme.md#includes)

Answer (score 3):

For me I had to set root parameter,

```
ejs.render(
  html,
  {},
  {
    root: process.cwd(),
  }
)
```

And then use it like,

```
<%- include('/footer/index.ejs'); %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try any of these:

```
<% include header.ejs %>
<% include header %>
<%- include('header.ejs'); -%>
<%- include('./header.ejs'); -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<% include header %>

    <h1>welcome</h1>

<% include footer%>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. VS Code
> 2. Left Side File Explorer
> 3. Right Click on the '.ejs' file
> 4. Click on 'Copy Path'
> 5. Then paste that path

```
<%- include('YOUR_PATH/GOES_HERE') %>
```

In my Case,
OS Ubuntu, Path was like this

```
<%- include('/media/username/diskname/foldername/nodejsApp/views/body/header.ejs') %>
```

**EDIT**

I forget '%' while writing answer.

Answer (score 0):

<%- include ('Filename without adding .ejs') %>

prerequisite: Ensure the filename correlates with the declared name in the above. i.e (Header is not equal to header.)

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the extension after the filename. For example, do this:

```js
include("file", { item: 123})
```

...not this:

```js
include("file.ejs", { item: 123})
```

If you have multiple includes in a loop, don't put the whole loop in one `<% %>` block. Put the beginning and end in their own `<% %>` and the includes in a `<%- %>` tag. It won't work with just a `<% %>` tag, you need to use `<%- %>`:

```js
<% for(const item of items) { %>
    <%- include("file", { item: 123}) %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced issues with this, but I add file extension, and it did work for me. Try the following way:

```
<%- include('header.ejs'); -%>

<%- include('footer.ejs'); -%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue,resolved with below

```
<%- include('header.ejs');-%>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <p><%=startingContent%></p>
<%- include('footer.ejs');-%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `home.ejs` file add this

```
  <%- include("../partials/header") %>
    <h1>Hi mom!</h1>
  <%- include("../partials/footer") %>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).