# EJS Could not find include include file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

This might sound like duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309842/could-not-find-include-include-file) and few others but the solutions given in those stack were not helpful.

I am creating an HTML using EJS templating, but while including a partial I am receiving following error :

```
 throw new Error('Could not find include include file.');
```

Below is the project structure

```
 |
 |
 |-----index.js
 |-----view
 |       |
 |       |----pages
 |       |      |----mainTemplate.ejs
 |       |----partials
 |       |      |----bodyTemplate.ejs
 |       |
```

Now as per doc the include takes relative path so code in my mainTemplate.ejs includes the bodyTemplate like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- Insert Body here -->
<div class="container">

    <div class="starter-template">
        <% include ../partials/bodyTemplate.ejs%>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

While code in bodyTemlate.ejs is

```
<% console.log("#########################");%>
<h1>Hi there !! </h1>
```

I am receiving **Could not find include include file**
This error is not much specific as to which path is being accessed here.

I have tried removing **..** from the path still no use? I have same project structure in my EJS application and this same code snippet works just fine? 
Is this something specific to express causing such issue?

**EDIT**

This is index.js

```
var fs = require('fs'),
  ejs = require("ejs");

function ejs2html(path, information) {
  fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
      return false;
    }
    var ejs_string = data,
      template = ejs.compile(ejs_string),
      html = template(information);
    fs.writeFile(path + '.html', html, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false
      }
      return true;
    });
  });
}
// console.log("This is path --> ", __dirname + '/view/pages/bodyTemplate.ejs');
ejs2html(__dirname + '/view/pages/mainTemplate.ejs');
```

Comment: did you forgot the parenthesis in include?

Comment: well I've a working code snippet without parenthesis, but will give it a shot if you say so

Comment: no parenthesis gives same error...

Comment: i mean like this `<% include("../partials/bodyTemplate.ejs") %>`

Comment: throw err;
  ^

Error: ejs:13
    11|
    12|     <div class="starter-template">
 >> 13|     <% include("../partials/bodyTemplate.ejs") %>
    14|     </div>
    15|
    16| </div>

Could not find include include file.

Comment: sorry for bad formatting in comment, but it gives same error just with stack trace

Comment: I tried your code and it's working on me, can you please post what your index.js is? How exactly are you rendering mainTemplate?

Comment: made an edit to question, thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was that you are trying to compile the html after you got it as a string from `fs` that way `ejs` has no idea where that file located and where to look for relative templates.

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    ejs = require("ejs");

function ejs2html(path, information) {
    fs.readFile(path, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err);
            return false;
        }
        var ejs_string = data,
            template = ejs.compile(ejs_string, {
                filename: path
            }),
            html = template(information);
        fs.writeFile(path + '.html', html, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return false
            }
            return true;
        });
    });
}
// console.log("This is path --> ", __dirname + '/view/pages/bodyTemplate.ejs');
ejs2html(__dirname + '/view/pages/mainTemplate.ejs');
```

Basically, I pass `{filename: path}` in order to tell `ejs` where the file is originally located.

Although I believe the thing you are trying to do, `ejs` has already implemented it with the `renderFile` method.
Check this alternate function that will do what you want.

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    ejs = require("ejs");

function ejs2html2(path, information) {
    ejs.renderFile(path, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + err);
            return false;
        }
        fs.writeFile(path + '.html', html, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return false
            }
            return true;
        });
    })
}
ejs2html2(__dirname + '/view/pages/mainTemplate.ejs');
```

Comment: This works cool, but in this case I had to remove the aforementioned parenthesis. Having parenthesis did not show the content of bodyTemplate.html