# EJS can't render template given as a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

My project structure

```
index.js
views
   ------partials
             --------login
             --------footer
   ------pages
            ---------index
```

Now i am rendering index.ejs via

```
res.render('pages/index',{template:'../partials/login'})}
```

In index.ejs i have

```
<% include (template) %>
```

I get this error `Error: Could not find include include file.`

I have view cache set to false. These are my project dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"ejs": "^2.5.7",
"express": "^4.16.3",
"express-generator": "^4.16.0"}
```

I tried giving abosulte path didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find include include file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46309842/could-not-find-include-include-file)

Answer (score -1):

The problem I think, is that you are including template as a string, and you are putting it in brackets. Try it like this:

```
<% include ../partials/login %>
```

What I think it is reading it as is:

```
<% include ('../partials/login') %>
```

Try that. I'm pretty sure it will work, because you have the most updated versions of your dependencies. Please tell me if that helped.

Comment: The syntax for includes [in the docs](http://ejs.co/#docs) shows that the parentheses are expected. If you put quotes around it, then it becomes a string literal, and the question is about using a variable.

Comment: So maybe you need to do this:

Comment: <%- include ('../partials/login') %>